# to eliminate strings from a bigger strings

Tags: c++

I am trying to eliminate sub strings from a string. I have the following code, it works, but when I implemented in an online judge, it gives back time limit exceeded error. Is there a better way to improve the algorithm time complexity? Also, if I want to not work in any way with the method substr, what do you see as an alternative?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <climits>
#include <string>
//#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    string s, s1, sub;
    getline(cin, s);
    getline(cin, sub);
    int l = s.length(), len = sub.length();
    int e = (l - len);
    for (int i = 0; i <= e; i++) {
        if (s.substr(i, len) == sub) {
            s = s.substr(0, i) + s.substr(i + len, l);
            cout << s;
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) the sub-string, and then [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) it?

Comment: As for possible improvements of your current code, an assignment to a variable (say e.g. `s1`) directly followed by another assignment to the same variable makes the first assignment kind of useless.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it is not allowed, you have to develop the algorithm yourself. The idea is not use any related substring string method.

Comment: The inputs are so large that creating all those substrings (and comparing them) takes too long. If you can't use `find`, you're going to have to write your own string-searching function. Any decent book on algorithms should contain a few of them.

Comment: @molbdnilo fair enough, thanks!

Comment: Do you have to remove all the occurrences of the pattern from the text?

Comment: @lucieon No, but it was solved.